# How to use @ReqeustBody with the @Query

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a @Query Annotation to SELECT data out of my Database,
but I want to add a Parameter to the SQL Query, to input data from a Request Body.
I don't know how to do that and can't find an example.

For Example, I have an abstract method inside my Repository:

```
@Query(value= "SELECT * FROM planets WHERE color= :body.getColor()", nativeQuery=true)
Iterable<Planet> getBody(Planet body);
```

And the Method in the Controller Class would look something like this:

```
@GetterMapping("/body")
Iterable<Planet> getBody(@ReqeustBody Planet body( { return Repository.getBody(body); }
```

In Postman I would do something like this:

```
GET |  http://localhost:8080/body | Body | raw | JSON: {"color":"red"}
```

Obviously this does not work and gives me error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : body.getColor()
```

My question is how would the syntex be like implementing a ReqeustBody into a @Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it simple way

```
@Query(value= "SELECT * FROM planets WHERE color=:color", nativeQuery=true)
Iterable<Planet> getBody(String color);
```

and pass `color` instead of `Planet`

```
return Repository.getBody(body.getColor())
```

It is possible to create custom extension to spring repository that would accept some abstract `HavingColor` object in general, but it requires some boilerplate code (not that much) and is just not worth of an effor (in the result, you will do `HavingColor.getColor()` anyway but on repository not the caller level).

Comment: Thank you so much, this really makes more sense!